# How to save processed images to different folders within a folder in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, save-image

I have code with looks through a folder 'Images' and then subfolders and processes all those images.

I now need to save those images to a parallel directory, i.e. a folder called 'Processed Images' (in same directory as 'Images' folder) and then to the subfolders within this folder - these subfolders are named the same as the subfolders in 'Images' - the image should save to the same name of subfolder that it came from.

I can get the images to save to 'Processed Images' but not the subfolders within it.

```
path = ("...\\Images")

for dirName, subdirList, fileList, in os.walk(path):

    for file in fileList:

        full_file_path = os.path.join(dirName, file)

        if file.endswith((".jpg")):

        image_file = Image.open(full_file_path)

        image_file = image_file.convert('L')

        image_file = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image_file)

        image_file = image_file.resize((28, 28))

        new_filename = file.split('.jpg')[0] + 'new.png'

        path2 = ("...\\Processed Images")

        image_file.save(os.path.join(path2, new_filename))

    else: continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `os.mkdir()` to create a new folder. `dirName` returned by `os.walk()` gives you the current folder path, so you can just extract the part of the path that you need, append it to `...\\Processed Images` and create the new folder if needed.

Be sure to use two separate folder trees for the input files and output files. Otherwise `os.walk()` will find the new directories with the output images and continue to iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can seriously simplify this code using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). I’m not sure about the triple dots (I think they should be double) in your base paths but they may work for you.

```
    from pathlib import Path
    path = Path("...\\Images")
    path2 = Path("...\\Processed Images")
    path2.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    for jpg_file in p.glob('**/*.jpg'):
        full_file_path = str(jpg_file)
        image_file = Image.open(full_file_path)
        image_file = image_file.convert('L')
        image_file = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image_file)
        image_file = image_file.resize((28, 28))

        new_filename = jpg_file.stem + 'new.png'
        image_file.save(str(path2 / new_filename))
```